# Being able to list Mobile Apps I've made on my profile. (Stack Overflow Centric)

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that employers like seeing your Stack Overflow profile sometimes.

Would there be any future where users could list their own apps out on stores?

Amazon, Google Play, iTunes, etc., and have them listed on their profile with app download buttons?

I know you guys could sign up to be an affiliate at the iTunes store and get some revenue sharing from this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show off links to those on your [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) profile.

For an example, see the "Apps & Software" section of [my profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/krahjerdi).

Comment: It isn't an open service entirely yet. Apparently, you have to prove you are a real programmer. I sent a request for an invitation, along with some links to a public github repo, a mobile app I've made, and my blog.  If I get approved and receive an invite, I'll mark this as an answer. : )

Comment: I guess, whether I'm accepted or not.. I have to accept this answer.  As it's the only one that will probably be given. : )